# What is --env=jsdom

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, jsdom

I was running my test suite for my react-native application with the command `jest`.

The tests would fail in the file `jest-runtime/build/index.js` on the line

```
const wrapper = this._environment.runScript(transformedFile.script)[
(_script_transformer || _load_script_transformer()).default.EVAL_RESULT_VARIABLE];
```

with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object.<anonymous>' of null
```

My version of jest is `21.2.1`.

Anyway, after some googling, I found that someone was running `jest --env=jsdom`. I gave that a try and then my test suite started working.

But what does this option mean?

I know that [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) is an implementation of the DOM and HTML standards.

But how is this useful to jest?
How does this change the behaviour of jest such that now the tests pass?

Comment: Do you override somewhere the `testEnvironment` property? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string. This would change the default `jsdom` library used. CLI has higher precedence and would override the value and make it work. Jsdom is required, as it is the headless browser used for testing components.

Comment: If you work in react it updates the vritual dom, not the real dom. Jest works without react this I think it's just extra info for what dom to read from. I can't however say this with being a 100% certain..

Comment: Here you can read about it in the documentation. Good luck
https://jestjs.io/ru/docs/cli#--envenvironment

Answer (score 28):

Because jest is a node module and is executed on your local machine (or in a CI environment) and not in the browser, it runs in a node context. This means that globals that you can access inside a browser context, such as `window` or `document` are not available. So if you access these global objects inside your code (or any other browser specific feature, such as `localStorage` for example) your tests will have to fail. The [option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#env-environment) `--env=jsdom` ensures that a mock browser environment is provided to your tests and thus allows them to pass.